# У меня or мне before не- words

Tags: местоимения

Which one is correctly written?

- У меня не с кем говорить
- Мне не с кем говорить

Thanks!

Comment: What did you mean to say? They are both correct, they just mean different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both grammatically correct, but mean different things:

*У меня не с кем говорить* means "There is none to talk to at my place".

*Мне не с кем говорить* means "I don't have anyone to talk to".

Note that using imperfective *говорить* in these sentences assumes some context:

> *— Поговори с кем-нибудь!
>   — Мне не с кем говорить.*

If you just want to state the fact you don't have anyone to talk to, use the perfective verb *поговорить*.

Comment: More specifically, I would like to say "I have no one to talk to in Russian where I live". Then it would become "у меня не с кем говорить на русском", right?

Comment: @swrutra: *у меня* in this particular construction means "at my something", like "place", "house", "job" etc. This assumes that there are no Russian speakers at this place, not necessarily for you to talk in Russian to, but for anyone. This is something you'd say to a Russian-only speaker if you invited them to your place: *приходи ко мне, но имей в виду: у меня не с кем поговорить по-русски* ("you're welcome to visit, but mind you, there is no one around to talk in Russian to at my place"), so this phrase is not about you, but about the place.

Comment: "I have no one to talk to in Russian where I live" would be *у меня мне не с кем поговорить по-русски*, if you wanted to emphasize that it's you who has no one to talk in Russian to at your place. Like if maybe there are some Russians around, but you'd rather not talk to them for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

*У меня [дома, на работе] не с кем говорить.*
*Мне [в принципе] не с кем говорить.*
Also may be 
*Мне не с кем **по**говорить*

Comment: Welcome to Russian SE

Answer (score 1):

The *second* version is correct (I have no one to talk to). The first one sounds like: 'there's nobody to talk to at my place'. However, **у меня** can be used in a longer construction like this:

> **У меня** **не**т никого, **с кем** можно было бы по**говорить**.